# Detectar palavra dentro de um elemento que esta dentro de uma class especifica

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código. Tentei executar dentro do elemento com a class ACTIVE, um código que verificava se tinha a palavra **VIOLET** dentro do elemento com a class **TITLE**. Mas em vez dele executar somente no elemento com a class ACTIVE, ele executava em todos que estavam com a palavra VIOLET:

```js
var Violet = /Violet/gi;

$('.title').append($('div').hasClass("active")).contents().each(function() {
  if (this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.match(Violet)) {
    alert('teste')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="owl-1">
  <div class="owl-item active">
    <li>
      <div class="title">Violet</div>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item">
    <li>
      <div class="title">Violet</div>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item">
    <li>
      <div class="title">Evergarden</div>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente o seguinte código pode resolver o problema:

```
var Violet = /Violet/gi;

if($("div.active .title").text().match(/Violet/gi)){
    alert('teste')
}
```

O selector $("div.active .title") pesquisa pelo elemento com a classe title dentro de um elemento div com a classe active.
O resultado será um array no caso de encontrar um valor ou null/undefined caso não exista nenhum elemento que corresponda a essa pesquisa.

Answer (score -1):

Muito obrigado LeAndrade e Samuelf. Com a ajuda de vocês 2, consegui fazer um código que atende as minhas necessidades.

```js
var violet = /Violet/gi;
 $('div.active').find('li').find('div.title').contents().each(function() {
  if(this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.match(violet)) {
  $('div.active').find('li').find('div.title').css('color','red');      
  } else{
    alert('Erro. O texto não é este!'); }});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="owl-1">
  <div class="owl-item active">
    <li>
      <div class="title">Violet</div>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item">
    <li>
      <div class="title">Violet</div>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item">
    <li>
      <div class="title">Evergarden</div>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Usar dois `find` é redundante: `$('div.active').find('li').find('div.title').css('color','red'); `... bastaria `$('div.active div.title').css('color','red');`... veja que não precisa nem de `.find()`